# vercel error: @prisma/client did not initialize yet. please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again

Tags: prisma, vercel, next.js13, mongodb-atlas

```
- info Linting and checking validity of types...
- info Collecting page data...
Error: @prisma/client/edge did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again.
In case this error is unexpected for you, please report it in https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues
    at new PrismaClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/.prisma/client/edge.js:3:11)
```

Above one is the problem I got when I deployed on vercel with MongoDb (atlas URL) backend and prisma as ORM.

I observe that @prisma/client instance is missing in deployment time . I have created separate file prisma object and using across the app.

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this with below steps

- update `package.json` file with `"build": "npx prisma db push && npx prisma generate && next build"`
- Update the Environment Variables in vercel with `NODE_ENV` as `production` also make sure updated `DATABASE_URL` with current Atlas connection string.

Above steps helps to solve my problem.